# Best way of using Django queryset where JSONField != {}

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-queryset, postgresql-performance

```
class JobAnalysis(Base, XYZ):
    env_vars = JSONField(
        default=dict
    )
    job = models.ForeignKey(
        Job, related_name='jobanalyses'
    )
    seller = models.ForeignKey(
        ABC,
        null=True
    )

class Usage(Base):
    job = models.ForeignKey(
        Job, null=True, blank=True
    )
```

I want all *usages* where env_vars has some key pair.

```
    usages_qs = Usage.objects.filter(
        job__jobanalyses__seller__isnull=True
    ).exclude(
        job__jobanalyses__env_vars__exact={}
    )
```

I am using above queryset to fetch all *usage* information where seller is null and env_vars is not equals {}

> usages_qs.query

```
SELECT "Usage"."job",
FROM "Usage"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Job" ON ("Usage"."job_id" = "Job"."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "JobAnalysis" ON ("Job"."id" = "JobAnalysis"."job_id")
WHERE ("JobAnalysis"."seller_id" IS NULL
       AND NOT ("Usage"."job_id" IN
                  (SELECT U2."job_id"
                   FROM "JobAnalysis" U2
                   WHERE U2."env_vars" = '{}')
                AND "Usage"."job_id" IS NOT NULL))
```

But I am seeing performance issue here because `.exclude(job__jobanalyses__env_vars__exact={})` create inner query and because of that this select statement is **timing out**.

Is there any better way of writing *Django queryset for getting all usage record where seller is null and env_vars != {}*?